# Как из DialogFragment обратится к Fragment-у который его вызвал?

Tags: java, android

Вызываю из фрагмента DatePickerFragment, ввожу дату и после вызывается onDateSet, как мне из него обратится фрагменту который его вызвал и изменить его?

Comment: Вы используете DatePickerFragment из библиотеки android-floatinglabel-widgets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17851838

Comment: Спасибо pavlofff, ответ в котором указано использование getTargetFragment() отличной подошел. DatePickerFragment наследник android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, использовал ссылку , которую предоставил pavlofff: stackoverflow.com/q/17851838

Answer (score 1):

1. Переопределить DatePickerFragment, добавить в конструктор параметр, например типа вашего фрагмента.
2. в момент, когда надо что-то сделать с фрагментом вызвать у переданного фрагмента определенный метод.
3. В этом методе фрагмента сделать все, что надо.

Если вы хотите предпринять действие по нажатию на ОК в диалоге, для этого есть встрренные средства. Покажите ваш код, как вы создаете и показываете диалог

Comment: Переопределить DatePickerFragment android не позволяет. Говорит использовать setArguments.

Answer (score 1):

Так же, как и с любым другим диалоговым фрагментом.
Как передавать события из диалогового фрагмента в вызывающую активность описано в [Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents). Здесь та же схема, только вместо `activity` используется `getParentFragment()`.

Создаем интерфейс `DatePickerListener`

```
public interface DatePickerListener {
    void onDateSet(DialogFragment dialog, int year, int month, int day)
}
```

В вызывающем фрагменте реализуем этот интерфейс.

```
public class ExchangeFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerListener {
     void onDateSet(DialogFragment dialog, int year, int month, int day {
          // ...
     }
}
```

Там же вызываем `DatePickerFragment`, только обязательно используем `getChildFragmentManager()`:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

В самом фрагменте `DatePickerFragment` получаем вызывающий фрагмент при помощи `getParentFragment()`:

```
OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        DatePickerListener target = (DatePickerListener) getParentFragment();
        target.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.this, dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Только через установку своего Listener'a. Как создавать слушателя написано [тут](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

Comment: Так же сначала думал, но не выйдет передать слушатель фрагменту.